# I want to grab href address which has class link

Tags: php, preg-match-all

[a href="http://www.vanchosun.com/m/market_index.php?view=market"]11[/a]

[a href="test.php?view=test&cate=buysell&testid=100" class="link"]22[/a]

How to grab href which has class link using php preg_match_all

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$pattern = '~(?(DEFINE)(?<class>\bclass\s*=\s*"[^"]*?\blink\b[^"]*"))
             <a\s+ [^>]*?
             (?| \g<class> [^>]*? \bhref\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"
               | \bhref\s*=\s*"([^"]*)" [^>]*? \g<class>)~xi';
preg_match_all($pattern, $code, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo '<br/>' . $match[1];
}
```

However peiman F. has a good answer, since the DOM is a better choice for this kind of task.

A DOM way:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($code);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    if (preg_match('~\blink\b~i', $link->getAttribute('class')))
        echo '<br/>' . $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for jobs like this its better to use php DOM

see the easy [how to use tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

use `DOMElement::getAttribute` method in all method list 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php